# How do you repeat the last ex command in a macro?

Tags: macro, repeated-commands

If I do `qq:diffthis<CR><C-w><C-w>@:q`, the macro `@q` does not work as expected, since the  command line history is not updated when ex commands are performed in macros, and consequently `@:` ignores the `:diffthis` command in the macro. Is there a way to allow macros to update the command line history, so that `@:` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you're asking about, but I'd do it like this:

<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`windo diffthis`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: `:windo` does the trick here! But I would still like to know if it is possible for `@:` to work in macros. As far as I can tell, macros are meant to repeat key sequences as if they were actually pressed, so it seems natural that `@:` should also work. Also, what is the purpose of the `2`? `windo diffthis` seems to do the trick by itself.

Comment: @AndyWang 1. "At" is treated like mapping. And mappings are only 99% like "true typing". This is all told in help. 2. By default windo applies to all windows in tab and there can be more than two of them.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info. As for `windo`, that was my point--the `2` in your answer seems redundant.

Comment: @AndyWang No one can get into your head except you. "Two" is needed to do it exactly as it's written in your question. If you really don't need it then just omit it.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Sorry, I wasn't aware that `windo` accepted a range and was confused about how the `2` was being used here. Thanks for the answer!